# Relative Layout Issue For Xoom Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having issues with layout for Xoom Tablet. Basically, I want one fragment (ListView) on the left side and the other fragment right to the ListView Fragment. But, I am having two issues on this.

Firstly, I dont want to hard code the android:layout_width for the listview fragment which is set to 200dip (Refer code below). I tried wrap_content, fill_parent but it didnt work for me.

Secondly, this UI is not rendered on the whole screen. Its only capturing a small portion of the whole tablet screen. Even hard coding from fill_parent to other values din't have any effect.

The code is as shown below. I would really appreciate any sort of help on this problem.

~Thank you !!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment"
        android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/titles"
        android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of hardcoding you can set the layout weight of each framelayout.  ie

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/items_layout" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
      android:layout_width="0px" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />

   <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/details_layout" 
    android:layout_weight="2"
      android:layout_width="0px" 
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="?android:attr/detailsElementBackground" />
```

Not sure why your UI isn't taking up the entire screen.  Are you supporting largeScreens, there is a setting in the manifest.

```
<supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true"  
    android:anyDensity="true">
</supports-screens>
```

Comment: Thank you ver much Bradley for your reply.